# How to animate the textview (very very long text )scroll automatically horizontally in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39529118/8678385) I made my textView to scroll horizontally for long texts,but after scrolling the RecyclerView,the scrolling animation of my textview's text gets stop.

The textView that I used in my custom layout for recyclerView:

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name_job"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="PeakyBlinders"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not add any code. You also forgot tag lanuage which you are using.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707140/5444161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Marquee text inside recyclerview!